'rn:federation:MicrosoftOnline' is unspecified or unsupported
When I logon to portal.office.com, I received the following:
"'rn:federation:MicrosoftOnline' is unspecified or unsupported"
But it works when I use the ADFS test URL "https://sts.contoso.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx".
Do I need to apply the "Replying Party Trust" by adding the "sts.contoso.com" in Federation metadata address?
